# EPPlus - Clear Entire Column From Worksheet

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

In EPPlus it's very easy to delete a column, the code is as follows:

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage())
{
    xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Summary");
    xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Summary"].DeleteColumn(21);
}
```

Is it possible to "not delete", but instead clear all values in a given column, maybe something like this?

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage())
{
    xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Summary");
    xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets["Summary"].Column(21).Clear();
}
```

I don't see a method for this in EPPlus, and while there are [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551557/epplus-to-clear-contents-of-a-range-of-cells) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21916041/2912011), I haven't found anyone else attempting to do this on entire columns.

Comment: A column is simply a range with a width of 1. Even a cell is a range with a width and height of 1. You can address an entire column the same way you address any range in excel, ie `B:B` will address the second column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @PanagiotisKanavos comment I've done it this way, should work, still wondering if there is another more elegant way to do it:

```
worksheet.Cells["U:U"].Clear();
```